# Use unserialize() to unserialize session data in console request?

Tags: php, session

I have a requirement where I have to change the session from CONSOLE request. Now console cannot access session. I do have figured out all this.
**I can not use session_decode() as I am in session.**

But I am having a problem with unserializing "SERIALILZED DATA" from the session.

I know session serialization is based on php.ini value.

; Handler used to serialize data php is the standard serializer of PHP.

session.serialize_handler = php

I want to know possible values I can set for session.serialize_handler in php_ini that will allow me to unserialize data in the console.

**Right now I am getting an exception. unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 8806 bytes.**

I know if I do set correct serialization handler value and then use same unserializer in WEB as well as CONSOLE. I can resolve the issue.

Let me know the possible solutions to overcome this situation.

Comment: Please include your code - how are you accessing the session data in the cli? How are you identifying the correct session? Are you using file based sessions?

Comment: I am using redis.  But it is working now.  I used value session.serialize_handler = php_serialize . which will use default PHP functions serialize and unserialize .

Comment: solution was changing session.serialize_handler = php to session.serialize_handler = php_serialize

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue because I was not able to unserialize serialized data. Because serialization was done with different function using the different parameter.

So I changed my php_ini to use session.serialize_handler from "php" to "php_serialize".

"php" and "php_serialize" both are different options one can set as per PHP docs.

so changing to php_serialize helped me do unserilaization with PHP function unserialize.